# svn merge --dry-run, How to show conflict details?

Tags: svn, merge

I like to dry run my merges first to look for conflicts, but all I can see is the amount of conflicts and which files are affected. It's not until after the merge that I can see the details of the conflict.

I'd like to be able to run a diff on the result of a dry-run merge, but I don't think this is possible. What's the next best way to see the details of your potential conflicts before committing yourself to a merge?

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure all changes to your working copy have been committed (best) or backed up by copying them elsewhere (adequate but usually pointless). Then do the merge. Merging is a working-copy operation. No changes will be committed to the repository, so if the conflicts are too hard to resolve right now just revert all changes to your working copy and deal with it later.

Comment: I like doing things that are "usually pointless"! Sometimes that minor step to backup your work will save your bacon! :-)